# Tapioca Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video, video-editing

[enter image descri[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FO3j.png)ption here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he7Sx.png)

how to fix this problem?

I need video color filter in flutter?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':tapioca' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.